# Running Yii2 queue/run in command line causes error on Windows Ampps

Tags: yii2

I am running Yii2 on Ampps on Windows and I have installed https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue

I am just trying to setup the supplied example but I am unable to even get that working.

What's happening is that when I run

```
Yii::$app->queue->push(new QueueLeadEmailJob([
    'url' => 'https://previews.123rf.com/images/fordzolo/fordzolo1506/fordzolo150600296/41026708-example-white-stamp-text-on-red-backgroud.jpg',
    'file' => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\websitedomain.com\41026708-example-white-stamp-text-on-red-backgroud.jpg',
]));
```

I am getting the correct value added to the queue table. When I run yii queue/run in the command line I get

```
2018-09-11 08:36:37 [pid: 4144] - Worker is started
2018-09-11 08:36:37 [3] common\components\queues\QueueLeadEmailJob (attempt: 1, pid: 4144) - Error
> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php-7.1\php.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\websitedomain.com\hub\yii queue/exec "3" "300" "1" "4144" --verbose=1 --color=" failed.
2018-09-11 08:36:37 [pid: 4144] - Worker is stopped (0:00:00)
```

I can see the error but I don't know how to resolve it. I have searched but (obviously) have not found a solution. After running yii queue/run the queue table is cleared so it seems like the queue is working...but no file is downloaded.

I have checked the permissions on the folder and it has write permissions.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [this bug](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/issues/258). It was already fixed in master, but not released yet. You may use master branch until version [`2.1.1`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/milestone/6) will be released.

```
composer require yiisoft/yii2-queue:dev-master
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a go and report back.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!